# LoadRunner and wicket application

Tags: wicket, loadrunner

Doing some research with regards to application framework used on the SUT am going to LoadTest using Loadrunner I fond the application is developed using wickets.

I have generated script using web http/html protocol against a wicket
application and there was some calls recorded in the following
format,script is failing at this URL when i ran the script in VUGen.

`http://somem/nnnweb/main/ ?
wicket:interface= :1:someSearchForm :someSearchForm :searchInfo: :IActi
vePageBehaviorListener :0:&wicket: ignoreIfNotActiv e=true&random=
0.038901654740178815",`

I find out like when i generate the script which has just views(
viewing tabs) is working fine, but when i edit somefileds and submit
the script is generating the above calls ( `http://xxx...`) and failing

This guy has explained just the same issue here:

`http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/LoadRunner/message/27295`

I hope it is ok to refer other sites in Stackoverflow?

General question. Does loadrunner support testing of wicket application and is TruClient the best choice here? I actually got it to work with TruClient, but as I understand there are drawbacks with memory footprint using TruClient, but maybe it is time to move on to next generation protocol given my project has decided to use wicket framework?

Comment: Using URL-recording mode and correlting a value made this work. Is it because URL-recording mode requests the server (and probably triggers some JavaScript I have behind a button) for each element being clicked?

Comment: You should answer your own question and then select your answer as the correct one.